# Error when start adonis - Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/@poppinss/file-generator/index.js'

Tags: node.js, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

When I start node ace serve --watch

Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/@poppinss/file-generator/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

What is actually @poppinss/file-generator ? why adonis search index.js on poppins?
[see my screen shoot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6FjN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you have made a clone of these repo, but ...

---

Follow these steps and try again:

1. npm install
2. .env.example .env
3. mkdir tmp
4. node ace migration:run   (if your project have a BD)
5. node ace serve --watch

---

Comment: hai, tks for coming, I solve the issue with change node version. I change to v14.19.0